# Serve static content with Jersey 2.22.2

Tags: java, rest, static, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have a REST Api that I developed using Jersey, everything works fine when it comes to Json in / out. and that I'm consuming by Ajax.

However, due to Cross-Domain limitations on the browsers, I'd like to package the static website (JS / Images / HTMLs / CSS) on my WAR

This is how my web.xml looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="RESTApi" 
    version="3.1">

    <display-name>RESTApi</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Test -> Jersey RESTful API</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.bc.api</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Test -> Jersey RESTful API</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and my static content on the project structure :

[image]

Now when I try to access `http://localhost:8080/static/index.html` it's processed as a REST call.

How can I make the static directory packages and accessed through the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use different url pattern for rest. For eample, for all rest api url pattern start with rest.http://localhost:8080/rest/ap/customer.

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="RESTApi" 
    version="3.1">

    <display-name>RESTApi</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Test -> Jersey RESTful API</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.bc.api</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Test -> Jersey RESTful API</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

For Static contents, you could **static** folder under **WebContent** directory, then you could access it :**http://localhost:8080/static/index.html**.

Comment: Thanks! What would be the path of the foder `webapp` ?

Comment: My project structure doesn't contain a `webapp` folder

Comment: The folder would be WebContent.